# Syslog-ng server

Tags: server

I'm doing a syslog server project for my summer training. I'm a novice but I'm sure the challenges the project will bring can give me a shot of becoming more proffessional and take up System Administration. I am using Ubuntu server 12.04 and I have installed syslog-ng. However, the command `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`, is returning:

```
 -bash:/etc/syslog-ng/sylog-ng.conf: Permission denied
```

What can I do to access the configuration file.

Comment: Which command are you running ?
Because /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf is not a command, it's the path to syslog-ng config file

Comment: i`m running sudo command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By typing just `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` in the command prompt, you are telling your shell to run the file. However, since the file has not been marked as executable (and it should not be, as it's a configuration file!), you'll get an error message. You would get the same error message by trying to run any file that does not have the +x bit set.

The file should be opened in a text editor. Configuration files residing in /etc are system-wide and editing them is restricted to the superuser only. By typing in `sudo gedit /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` and entering your password when asked, you'll get a text editor to edit the file and save any changes you'll make.

Answer (score 0):

Type your command with `sudo` before:

```
sudo <command>
```

`sudo` allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser/root, as specified by the security policy.

Also, when you want to execute something from a file, be sure that the file can be executed with:

```
chmod +x <file>
```

Comment: I`m using sudo already

Comment: @sosytee Most likely your file cannot be executed. See my new edits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the file, you need to use an editor.  Typing

vi /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

will open the file using the [Vim](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html) editor.

Comment: And you may want to elevate the privileges using `sudo` in order to be able to actually save the file.